# Inbuilt way to get a key value pair in .net?

Tags: .net

I have a string like this:

"MyPropery=Value"

Is there a quick way (using built in .net) to convert this a useable keyValuePair (or similar object) ?

One solution would be to use split, but I'm looking for something more specific than a list of items, since only 2 key + value would exist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get this string from? Can you give a more complete example?

Comment: If there is I never found it ended up writing a NamedValues Class that hides a Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Split them manually and stick them in a `Dictionary<String, String>`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = @"Key1=Value1
                    Key2=Value2
                    Key3=Value3=Value4
                    FooBar";

    var result = CreateKeyValuePairs(input);

    foreach (var kvp in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    // Access specific item by key:
    Console.WriteLine(result["Key2"]);
}

private static Dictionary<String, String> CreateKeyValuePairs(string input)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<String, String>();

    foreach (var line in input.Split('\n'))
    {
        var kvp = line.Trim();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp))
        {
            int equals = kvp.IndexOf('=');
            if (equals > 0)
            {
                var key = kvp.Substring(0, equals);
                var value = kvp.Substring(equals + 1);

                // You might want to trim the key and value
                result.Add(key, value);
            }
            else
            {
                // Invalid key/value-pair
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```